# Keras GRU/LSTM layer input dimension error

Tags: python, keras, nlp, deep-learning, lstm

I am kind of new to deep learning and I have been trying to create a simple sentiment analyzer using deep learning methods for natural language processing and using the Reuters dataset. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import reuters
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, GRU
from keras.utils import np_utils
max_length=3000
vocab_size=100000
epochs=10
batch_size=32
validation_split=0.2
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = reuters.load_data(path="reuters.npz",
                                                         num_words=vocab_size,
                                                         skip_top=5,
                                                         maxlen=None,
                                                         test_split=0.2,
                                                         seed=113,
                                                         start_char=1,
                                                         oov_char=2,
                                                         index_from=3)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_length)

x_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_train, mode='binary')
x_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_test, mode='binary')
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 50)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 50)


model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(50, input_shape = (49,1), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(max_length,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_split)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('Test Accuracy:', round(score[1]*100,2))
```

What I do not understand is why, every time I try to use a GRU or LSTM cell instead of a Dense one, I get this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected gru_1_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (8982, 3000)

I have seen online that adding `return_sequences = True` could solve the issue, but as you can see, the issue remains in my case.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Your `x_train.shape` is `(8982, 3000)` - where does `input_shape = (49,1)` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the shape of `x_train` is `(8982, 3000)` so it means that (considering the preprocessing stage) there are 8982 sentences encoded as one-hot vectors with vocab size of 3000. On the other hand a GRU (or LSTM) layer accepts a sequence as input and therefore its input shape should be `(batch_size, num_timesteps or sequence_length, feature_size)`. Currently the features you have are the presence (1) or absence (0) of a particular word in a sentence. So to make it work with GRU you need to add a third dimension to `x_train` and `x_test`:

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1)
```

and then remove that `return_sequences=True` and change the input shape of GRU to `input_shape=(3000,1)`. This way you are telling the GRU layer that you are processing sequences of length 3000 where each element consists of one single feature. (As a side note I think you should pass the `vocab_size` to `num_words` argument of `Tokenizer`. That indicates the number of words in vocabulary. Instead, pass `max_length` to `maxlen` argument of `load_data` which limits the length of a sentence.)

However, I think you may get better results if you use an [Embedding layer](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) as the first layer and before the GRU layer. That's because currently the way you encode sentences does not take into account the order of words in a sentence (it just cares about their existence). Therefore, feeding GRU or LSTM layers, which relies on the order of elements in a sequence, with this representation does not make sense.